# How to find the Id and put it in a new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm a beginner with R and I use `tidyverse` package.

I have data like this

```
ID   Jobs    Successors
1    JobA    JobB;JobC
2    JobB    JobD
3    JobC    JobD
4    JobD
```

and I want to add a column with the Successors ids so that the data look likes

```
ID   Jobs    Successors    SuccessorIds
1    JobA    JobB;JobC     2;3
2    JobB    JobD          4
3    JobC    JobD          4
4    JobD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr` to divide data on different rows based on `";"`, `match` `Successors` and `Jobs` to get corresponding `ID`'s, `group_by` `ID` and `Jobs` and paste the data.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(Successors, sep = ";") %>%
  mutate(SuccessorIds = ID[match(Successors, Jobs)]) %>%
  group_by(ID, Jobs) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Successors, SuccessorIds), paste0, collapse = ";")


#    ID Jobs  Successors SuccessorIds
#  <int> <fct> <chr>      <chr>       
#1     1 JobA  JobB;JobC  2;3         
#2     2 JobB  JobD       4           
#3     3 JobC  JobD       4           
#4     4 JobD  NA         NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Jobs = structure(1:4, .Label = c("JobA", 
"JobB", "JobC", "JobD"), class = "factor"), Successors = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("JobB;JobC", "JobD"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 5):

One option involving `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(SuccessorsIds = map(.x = strsplit(Successors, ";", fixed = TRUE),
                            ~ ID[match(.x, Jobs)]))

  ID Jobs Successors SuccessorsIds
1  1 JobA  JobB;JobC          2, 3
2  2 JobB       JobD             4
3  3 JobC       JobD             4
4  4 JobD       <NA>            NA
```

And if you don't want a list, but a character vector:

```
df %>%
 mutate(SuccessorsIds = map_chr(.x = strsplit(Successors, ";", fixed = TRUE),
                                ~ paste0(ID[match(.x, Jobs)], collapse = ";")))

  ID Jobs Successors SuccessorsIds
1  1 JobA  JobB;JobC           2;3
2  2 JobB       JobD             4
3  3 JobC       JobD             4
4  4 JobD       <NA>            NA
```

Answer (score 5):

`str_replace_all()` in `stringr` can replace matched patterns in a string. The advantage is that it can apply multiple patterns and replacements to the same string by passing a **named vector**. Here I use `setNames()` to create a named vector to specify the patterns and replacements.

```
df %>%
  mutate(SuccessorIds = str_replace_all(Successors, setNames(as.character(ID), Jobs)))

#   ID Jobs Successors SuccessorIds
# 1  1 JobA  JobB;JobC          2;3
# 2  2 JobB       JobD            4
# 3  3 JobC       JobD            4
# 4  4 JobD       <NA>         <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

- Make a lookup table from Jobs to ID
- Split Successors
- Look up IDs
- Re-join with ';'

```r
library(tidyverse)
df = read_table('ID   Jobs    Successors
1    JobA    JobB;JobC
2    JobB    JobD
3    JobC    JobD
4    JobD')

# lookup for ID
id_lookup = df$ID %>% set_names(df$Jobs)

df$SuccessorIds = str_split(df$Successors, ';') %>% 
  map_chr(~id_lookup[.x] %>% paste(collapse=';'))
df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      ID Jobs  Successors SuccessorIds
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <chr>       
#> 1     1 JobA  JobB;JobC  2;3         
#> 2     2 JobB  JobD       4           
#> 3     3 JobC  JobD       4           
#> 4     4 JobD  <NA>       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `strsplit()` + `match()`

```
df$SuccessorsIds <- apply(df, 1, function(v) paste0(match(unlist(strsplit(v["Successors"],split = ";")),df$Jobs),collapse = ";"))
```

such that

```
> df
  ID Jobs Successors SuccessorsIds
1  1 JobA  JobB;JobC           2;3
2  2 JobB       JobD             4
3  3 JobC       JobD             4
4  4 JobD       <NA>            NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this easily with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
df$SuccessorIds <- gsubfn("(\\w+)", setNames(as.list(df$ID),df$Jobs), df$Successors)
df
#   ID Jobs Successors SuccessorIds
#1  1 JobA  JobB;JobC          2;3
#2  2 JobB       JobD            4
#3  3 JobC       JobD            4
#4  4 JobD       <NA>           NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Jobs = c("JobA", "JobB", "JobC", "JobD"
), Successors = c("JobB;JobC", "JobD", "JobD", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's verbose, but splitting by ";", self-joining, and collapsing again seems flexible and (at least for how I think & work) pretty legible.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(Successors, sep = ";") %>%
  left_join(x = ., y = ., by = c("Successors" = "Jobs")) %>%
  select(ID = ID.x, Jobs, Successors, SuccessorsIds = ID.y) %>%
  group_by(ID, Jobs) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Successors, SuccessorsIds), paste, collapse = ";")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>      ID Jobs  Successors SuccessorsIds
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <chr>        
#> 1     1 JobA  JobB;JobC  2;3          
#> 2     2 JobB  JobD       4            
#> 3     3 JobC  JobD       4            
#> 4     4 JobD  NA         NA
```